# Swift Decodable: Inject value in nested generic property

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

I have this API response structure (from Strapi v4):

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
                "description": "test",
            }
        }
    ]    
}
```

I have this generic code to handle API responses and to inject the ID to my child object:

```swift
struct StrapiArrayResponse<Content: StrapiDataObjectContent>: Codable {
    var data: [StrapiDataObject<Content>]
}

struct StrapiDataObject<Content: StrapiDataObjectContent>: Codable {
    let id: Int
    var attributes: Content
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container: KeyedDecodingContainer<CodingKeys> = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.attributes = try container.decode(Content.self, forKey: .attributes)
        self.attributes.id = id
    }
}

protocol StrapiDataObjectContent: Codable {
    var id: Int! { get set } // I don't want this to be an Optional
}
```

I want my id to be a `let` instead of an optional `var`.

Is there a better way to inject the ID to my child objects (`StrapiDataObjectContent`)?

Comment: Why did you make it optional in the first place? I am not sure I follow.

Comment: To be able to inject the id property in the initializer of the outer object. Since the id is not in the attributes json object

Comment: Ok, and you don't want it to be a `var` either but a `let`. And you can't use  StrapiDataObject.id instead since it will always be the same?

Comment: Yes, like I said, I want it to be a let. More importantly not an Optional.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself a bit but making it a non optional variable is trivial while making it a constant is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for the problem but it isn't so straightforward and requires some work.

Since you want `id` to be a constant we need a way to initialise `Content` with it so one way then is to add an `init` to the protocol.

```
protocol StrapiDataObjectContent: Codable {
    var id: Int { get } //also removed 'set'
    init(id: Int, copy: Self)
}
```

As you see this init takes an already existing object as parameter so this is kind of a copy method

So an implementation (based on the json in the question) could then be

```
init(id: Int, copy: Test) {
    self.id = id
    self.description = copy.description
}
```

We then need to change `init(from:)` in `StrapiDataObject` to

```
 init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container: KeyedDecodingContainer<CodingKeys> = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    let attributes = try container.decode(Content.self, forKey: .attributes)
    self.attributes = Content(id: id, copy: attributes)
}
```

Now this compiles but we will get a runtime error since `id` is expected by the decoder for `Content` but doesn't exists in the json.

So this leads to the major drawback of this solution, every type conforming to `StrapiDataObjectContent` needs to implement a custom `init(from:)` just to avoid decoding the `id` property

To demonstrate here is a full example (based on the json in the question)

```
struct Test: StrapiDataObjectContent {
    let id: Int
    let description: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        id = 0
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
    }

    init(id: Int, copy: Test) {
        self.id = id
        self.description = copy.description
    }
}
```

Comment: @heyfrank any feedback on this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah this is too much of a drawback, as you mentioned yourself. I was rather looking for a custom implementation of `KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol` that allows me to inject keyed values.
Will accept your answer anyway, since it's working.